# What is the difference between Data Modeling and Data Processing?

Tags: data-analysis, apache-spark, apache-hadoop

When discussing big data, it is sometimes mentioned that data modeling can be done by using a tool like map reduce, while data processing may be performed by apache spark. What is the difference between data modeling tasks, and data processing tasks? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Data modeling means representing the data, usually with a somewhat compact model. Modeling implies simplifications: this can lead to a good model which reliably represents the patterns in the data or a terrible model which simplifies too much or not enough.
- Data processing is applying any kind of process to the data.

For the record, map-reduce is relevant only as a technique for processing large data efficiently.

Comment: Could you refer a good site for learning modelling?

Comment: @user17302 modelling is very specific to the domain, task, data. For example I'm doing NLP so I know techniques for representing text data, I know the type of features needed for different tasks in NLP, etc. That would be totally different for images, biomedical data... Basically you should choose which domain/application you're interested in imho.